# Page Loading Time in Jmeter

Tags: performance, time, load, jmeter, performance-testing

I would like to measure loading time of a document in my testing web app. I have used JMeter for this, but I am getting different values for each run. I am measuring average time in the summary report.

I am not sure, that the value is proper or not.Is this approach is correct or Is there any plugin JMeter available?

I have used HTTP watch to get rendering time, but I can't use that tool for more than 1 user (Load Testing). I am using JMeter 2.13. Could you please help me in this?

Answer (score 6):

1. With the help of aggregate report or csv / xml results you get required information regarding response times BUT

   - In Jmeter, Response time = Processing time + Latency(time taken by network while transferring data)
   - In Browser, Response time = Processing time + Latency + Rendering time
     Hence you will found a difference between http watch response times and jmeter response times.

If you need to include rendering times also in your response times, then use tools, like loadrunner (commercial), selenium (open source) and so on. Personally in my opinion client side rendering is not a measurable value, unless all of the users accessing the application are having same configuration of hardware, software and network access. However, while JMeter test running with peak load to the system, manually browse the site using various browsers and with the help of developer tools you can find rendering times.

2. **I am getting different values for each run** - this will depends upon test data you are using, server health status, network delays and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info. can we get rendering time using Jmeter?

Comment: No...As per my knowledge we can't get rendering times using jmeter. To capture the rendering times we need to use tools which will work at GUI level like selenium, loadrunner and so on.

Comment: If you are waiting for rendering time, the time required to write information to the screen once all components have been downloaded and the DOM has been processed, then you are too late to make the architectural changes required to affect page loading and rendering.  You need to have every developer examining the times in the developer tab as the page is developed. http://bit.ly/1ORhrNj

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you'll be able to get 2 fully identical test run results, there always will be some form of fluctuation caused by underlying hardware and software implementations. You should be receiving similar results with some statistical noise.

If this is not the case, your JMeter test might be misconfigured. From  "realness" perspective mind the following configuration:

- Make sure you have **Retrieve All Embedded Resources from HTML Files** box checked and you **Use concurrent pool**. The easiest way to configure it for all the samplers is using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults)
- Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to your test plan. Previous setting "tells" JMeter to fetch embedded resources like scripts, styles, etc. from the pages. Real browsers do it as well but they do it only once, on subsequent requests these resources are being returned from browser's cache.
- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan. It represents browser cookies, enables cookie-based authentication and maintains sessions.
- Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to represent browser headers like User-Agent, Content-Type, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 2):

When you use a straight HTTP Protocol layer virtual user, independent of the tool (Jmeter, LoadRunner, SOASTA, Grinder, ...) then what you will be timing will be the request/response information coming from the server with very low coloration from the local processing on the client for JavaScript and the final "drawing on the screen" which is rendering.

Up until the point where the server is degraded due to number of requests or network limitations the only area where you can tune is in the page architecture, which if you are waiting to the last 100 yards before deployment to address then you are likely in trouble.

Steve Souders has written quite a bit on the subject of page architecture in his books "High Performance Websites" and related works.  In short, the rule of thumb comes down to making fewer requests, smaller responses and serving the data from the closest possible location to the client.  These have the effect of minimizing the most expensive finite resource to a web client, the network.  For instance, a browser sprite reduces the number of calls for images, minification and compression reduce the size of the transmission and a CDN changes the number of hops to the requested item to a location closer to the end client.

In order to affect changes to page architecture you need to move upstream into your development cycle and your functional testing cycle.  You will need to work with development to implement hard gates where code/pages cannot be submitted to the project without first passing performance gates related to design.  Your development team and functional testing members will need to respect those gates.  As to what the gates should be, I refer you back to the works of Mr Souders as a great source of data for construction of your gate rules.

This gets you to the level of "works for one: Performant for one."  Then you can use that as a known good to answer the questions related to server scalability and at which point the service to the client from requests begins to degrade.   If you have a CDN in your organization, be sure to take that into account in your test model, for if you do not then you will overload your server vs production.

As far as actual speeding of the "rendering" or drawing on the screen?  You need to purchase a faster video card barring changes from the browser manufacturer.  Speeding up JavaScript?  Make sure that all of your JavaScript is as small and as lean as possible.  Have your functional test team test on very dirty browsers with lots of add-ins as well as lower powered hardware for a view of maximum out of spec response.  If you need a view of what your standard hardware model looks like from your clients (Browser/OS/some hardware into) then you can process the data in your HTTP request logs and specifically the user agent related to client configuration information.